# JavaMelody - monitoring path param is ignored after JDK upgrade

Tags: java, tomcat, java-melody

After upgrade from Java7 to Java8_u60 JavaMelody's `monitoring-path` param defined in `web.xml` is being ignored. In the log does not contain any useful information. I was exploring the JavaMelody guide, but I have not found nothing.

The monitoring section was defined to path `www.domain.com/xxx/monitoring` but after Java upgrade is in the default location `www.domain.com/monitoring`.
Does anyone have any experiences with this issue?
my `web.xml` conf:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>javamelody</filter-name>
    <filter-class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>monitoring-path</param-name>
        <param-value>/xxx/monitoring</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>url-exclude-pattern</param-name>
        <param-value>/resources/.*</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>javamelody</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ASYNC</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>net.bull.javamelody.SessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Used technologies:
*JavaMelody 1.57.0, Apache Tomcat 7, Spring*

Comment: We are experiencing same issue in similar environment. We first noticed it on version _JavaMelody 1.55.0._ At the same time we upgraded Java 7 to Java 8. So may be Java upgrade is the reason.

Comment: I can confirm, with version 1.55.0 is the same. I've created the ticket on [JavaMelody's github](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/issues/498), but I have not got any feedback yet.

Comment: Did you consulted [https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/issues/detail?id=459](issue 459)? Some workarounds and explanations are described there. Issue is closed, so there is a big chance that it will help.

Comment: I didn't. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the solution is described in [issue 459.](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/issues/detail?id=459#c4)

- You can either config JavaMelody using `context-param` in your `web.xml` (by default JavaMelody is configured through `web-fragment.xml` in its jar file, so by using context params you override its settings in `web.xml`)
- Or just use any other filter name instead of "monitoring" (in this case filter settings in `web-fragment.xml` are ignored, but settings from application `web.xml` are activated)